# from csv file :Convert unix timestamp of first column into year and create a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create a plot from csv file. In the csv file, the first column is timestamp, second till sixth column are different parties. I want to create a graph where x axis is year(ie. 2004) and plot the graph with the values of the parties in percentage in y axis.

The csv file looks like:

```
 date,CSU/CDU,SPD,Gruene,FDP,Linke
 891468000.0,34,44,6,5,6
 891986400.0,34,44,6,5,6
 892677600.0,35,43,6,5,5
 894405600.0,32,46,6,6,5
 895010400.0,33,46,5,5,5
```

I have tried the below code.

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 with open('polldata.csv') as f:

    names = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',')

 cols = data.shape[1]
 for n in range (1,cols):     
     plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,n],label=names[n])

 plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=14)
 plt.ylabel('parties',fontsize=14)  

 plt.show()
```

From the first column of my csv file, I want to convert that timestamp to year .Also, I need to display in a bar chart so that the color differentiation parties can be easily identified.

I want the graph to look similar like the 5TH one in the below page

(https://moderndata.plot.ly/elections-analysis-in-r-python-and-ggplot2-9-charts-from-4-countries/)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: could you please convert one of the timestamps? I can extend the answer below to reflect that then...

Comment: from datetime import datetime

                      ts= int(891468000.0)   

                print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y'))
                output: 1998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the csv reader from pandas. Documentation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

it looks like this:

import pandas as pd

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("polldata.csv", delimiter=',')

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda ts: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y'))
print(df)

ols = df.columns
for n in range (len(cols)):
    plt.plot(df,label=cols[n])

plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('parties',fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

it will print:

```
   date  CSU/CDU  SPD  Gruene  FDP  Linke
0  1998       34   44       6    5      6
1  1998       34   44       6    5      6
2  1998       35   43       6    5      5
3  1998       32   46       6    6      5
4  1998       33   46       5    5      5
```

does that get you started?

Comment: @Beyer: I want to convert the first column of the csv file which is a unix time stamp into a year and then plot graph accordingly

Comment: I just want only the year

Comment: from datetime import datetime

ts= int(891468000.0)   
 
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y'))
                                            output: 1998

Comment: for eg., if we convert the unix time stamp of 891468000.0 gives us the year 1998. I want to do that for the first column of the csv file and then plot the graph for the same

Comment: welcome - let me know if we should refine the graph any further

Comment: yes, it would be grateful, if you help me ploting the graph also for the above code

Comment: I would suggest to generate an svg file as plot .SVG is normalized and standardised file format. you next can convert it in any other kind of formats

Comment: @Beyer: It says object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @Beyer , I guess its c missing your code (line 6) (ols ) . but even after adding c ie., cols. its not working. it says: 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. please help me here